# Java inner class this

Tags: java

From an inner class, is it preferred to use `OuterClass.this.someMethod()`, or just simply `someMethod()` (of course given there's no ambiguity and compiler doesn't complain).

Comment: `of course given there's no ambiguity` There may be times where you don't know if there will be any amibguity. So I would say always use `OuterClass.this.someMethod()` to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more the question of taste. Some people always use `this` qualifier when accessing class members. I personally do not do this because this makes code more verbose.

Explicit qualifying of outer class' this is even more verbose. One additional argument is that it can cause some problems when refactoring your code (unless your IDE does this correctly).